# Выбор key-value storage

Tags: c++, nosql

Необходимо обеспечить доступ к набору данных вида (key, value) где key - числовой идентификатор, а value - динамический массив. На С++ я описал бы структуру так:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int time;
    double value;
} item;

typedef std::unordered_map<long long, std::vector<item> > my_storage;
```

Но, к сожалению датасет не помещается в оперативную память. Поэтому нужно выбрать какое-то хранилище данных. Задача имеет следующие особенности:

1. Длина динамических массивов распределена экспоненциально (половина массивов вообще состоят из одного элемента).
2. Хранилище заполняется постепенно: данные вида `std::pair<long long, item>` поступают отсортированные по полю item.time и добавляются в конец соответствующего динамического массива.
3. Хранилище должно обеспечивать операции двух видов: чтение целого массива по ключу и добавление одного элемента в конец соответствующего ему массива
4. Вероятность обращения к конкретному массиву зависит от поля `item.time` последнего элемента массива (тоже экспоненциально). Так как каждый массив отсортирован по возрастанию `item.time`, можно сказать, что вероятность обращения зависит от времени последнего обращения к нему.

Я нагуглил несколько вариантов таких хранилищ: [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html), [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/)... Даже [бенчмарк](http://symas.com/mdb/microbench/july/) нашел:

Требования к базе такие:

1. Возможность хранения значений переменной длины (наверное все могут - строки-то хранить как-то научились).
2. Если массив-значение длинный, не перезаписывать его полностью, а только конец с добавленным элементом.
3. Кэширование наиболее часто запрашиваемых массивов.
4. Желательно, чтобы база была встраиваемой. Не хочется терять время на сериализацию и сетевое взаимодействие. Сервер-то один.

Данных будет где-то 50-200 Gb (это если слепить в один массив все структуры типа item).

Ну, собственно, прошу помочь тех, кто  работал с перечисленными выше БД. Или, может, что-нибудь другое предложите?

**UPD:**
Забыл добавить, что задание скорее учебное, поэтому ни транзакции, ни конкурентный доступ с большого числа клиентов, ни постоянная синхронизация не нужны.

Нашел еще решение: [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html). Позиционируется как раз, как хранилище для научных данных. Кто работал с ним, можете прокомментировать?

Еще хотел спросить у знающих людей, какие FS + mount options использовать, чтобы избежать ненужного журналирования?

Comment: Из перечисленных, даже по бенчмаркам видно, LevelDB показывает лучшие результаты. Еще facebook недавно открыл свою RocksDB, которая вроде бы как быстрее чем LevelDB. К нем обеим есть обертка SSDB - http://www.ideawu.com/ssdb/, которая реализует интерфейс Redis'а. Т.е. то что вам нужно (List). Но эта обертка работает через сетевой сокет. В общем то исходники открыты можно переписать. По крайней мере заменить на unix сокет там не сложно.
Ваш вопрос от 5-го марта. Вероятно вы уже как то его решили. Было бы интересно узнать на чем вы остановили свой выбор.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал LevelDB, но со сложным ключом (основной идентификатор + номер в массиве или time), чтобы значением был только один элемент, а не массив.

Поскольку в LevelDB данные отсортированы по ключу, то можно пробежаться по следующим/предыдущим ключам и получить весь массив.

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы превели, в качестве примера - не предназначенно для этого, как минимум, будет очень медленно. Для таких объемов, скорее что-то на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop с https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra.